# cakephp query japanese words

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

I am using postgresql with cakephp.database contains japanese data.i want to use them in my query.
                if i use `$this->Model->query("select * from table_name where field_name='test'");`
                it works fine.

but when i use  `$this->Model->query("select * from table_name where field_name='テスト'");`
                i am not getting the result.
                        my database is in  `UTF8` ,in `$default 'encoding' => 'utf8'` is written and i used `utf8` in meta tag too.
                        how to resolve this?

Comment: `$this->Model->query("select *` query only be used as a last resort - `find` doesn't work? Does `select * from table_name where field_name='テスト'` return results when issued directly in the db?

Comment: Yes it is working.i cant use 'find' because i am dealing with temp tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know what is wrong but

```
$field = iconv('shift-jis', 'utf-8', $field);
$this->Model->query("select * from table_name where field_name='$field'");
```

Worked for me. thanks for your answers